# ActiveMQ Artemis JMX access

Tags: jmx, activemq-artemis

I would like to know if there is a way to access values of MBeans in Apache Artemis. The problem is that MBeans access is protected by role access defined in `management.xml`. When you are accessing MBeans you should have role required in settings, but from my Java app I cannot apply role when I'm accessing MBeans. Same thing happens when I use VisualVM, I can see list of MBeans but due to access constraint I cannot see value of MBeans.

One workaround is to actually remove `<authorization>` element from `management.xml` or to simply add `org.apache.activemq.artemis` in `<whitelist>` element.

It would be nice if I could do it via reflection in runtime. I've tried couple of times but didn't have much success. Is there a way to override any of Artemis' properties in runtime and that way make access possible?

Comment: What do you mean by, "from my Java app I cannot apply role"? Roles are applied by the broker in response to the client's credentials (i.e. username & password or SSL certificate). You don't need to specify anything related to role from the client application.

Comment: I'm not using Artemis with a client library. I'm trying to read MBean values in my Java app using JMX. Problem is I cannot access MBean values because my Java app does not have required access in order to get values of every Artemis MBean.

Comment: Strange thing is that if I run Artemis in debug mode all MBean values are present, and also VisualVM can access those values.

Comment: Why can't you pass username & password from your application using JMX?

Comment: Well, I'm trying not to use connection port (1099) in order to access MBeans. That's why I've asked if reflection could help me access these MBeans. There is ```JMXAccessControlList``` which I could extend with ```org.apache.activemq.artemis``` (whitelist), but something funny is happening when I try to use it through reflection.

Comment: Please clarify how you're attempting to access the MBeans.

Comment: Simply using MBeanServerProxy with  ```firstMBean()```  and ```queryMBean()``` methods. The thing is, methods can find specific MBean, but value is always ```null```.

Comment: You should edit your question and add those details about how you're accessing the MBeans. A code example would help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MBean access restriction is part of the security of the broker. Having a way to circumvent that security or just disable it at runtime without the proper authentication & authorization would be a significant security hole. If MBean access wasn't restricted then anyone with remote access could shut the broker down or even delete all the messages in your queues.

If you want to access the MBeans without restriction you'll need to change `management.xml` as you noted.

You could also just submit the proper username & password from your application so that the broker would grant you access.

Comment: I thought so. Then I will go without authorisation in ```management.xml```. Thanks for clarification.